# CORS error on axios POST request to backend

Tags: javascript, http, cors, axios

I was using AJAX for sending login req to the backend. But I tried to do the same thing with axios but getting cors error.
This is my req.

The CORS response has already been set up in the backend.

```
      .post('https://testconsole.pva.com/j_spring_security_check', {
        data: {
          j_username: email,
          j_password: password
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        crossorigin: true,
        headers: {

          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
          'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type'
        }

      })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseUrl: “https://testconsole.pva.com”,
  headers: {
    common: {  
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'WithCredentials': true,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
....
const myRequest = await api({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/j_spring_security_check',
  data: JSON.stringify({
          j_username: email,
          j_password: password
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use proxy
the file vue.config.js  add url cors error url
eg: your url https://example.com/ and error url https://testconsole.pva.com/j_spring_security_check

add these line to your config file

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'https://testconsole.pva.com/'
    },
}
```

then you can try url https://example.com/j_spring_security_check